# Best practices for attaching a variable to XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET','example.php');
xhr.myVar=0;
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  this.myVar=this.responseText.length;
  var s=this.readyState+":"+this.myVar+":"+this.responseText;
  document.getElementById('x').innerHTML=s;
  };
```

I have this script on a web page (and a `<p id="x"></p>`). I want to attach a variable for use in the `onreadystatechange` function (obviously, in the real code I do something more interesting with it than I do here).

This works fine in the browsers I've tried it in, but it makes me nervous. Is there a convention I should be following? E.g. prefix custom variables with underline, or something like that?

BTW, attaching a member variable otherwise feels exactly right: the main alternative is use a global variable, which I don't like at all (I might have two XMLHttpRequest objects on the page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Assuming this ajax request is inside a function body, then you can declar `myVar` using `var` keyword and use it inside the `onreadystatechange` function as if it is a local variable.

```
function x() {

    ....
    ....

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'example.php');
    var myVar = 0;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        this.myVar = this.responseText.length;
        var s = this.readyState + ":" + myVar + ":" + this.responseText;
        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML = s;
    };

    ....
    ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. Did you mean `this.myVar = ...` or was that a typo for `myVar = ...`?

Comment: it is not `this.myVar`, if you want to use closure it should be `var myVar = 0;`

Comment: Arun, what I meant was: your first line of onreadystatechange() looks like the `this.` part is a typo, and it should read `myVar = this.responseText.length;`. (But I don't want to edit your answer in case I've misunderstood your intention and it is not a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is already pretty okay. You're not polluting the global scope, attaching to something you know you will already have in the function (as the function onreadystatechange is called with `this` set to the XHR object). However, there are a few things you might want to improve on:

- Your variable name is fine as it is now. What if you want/need to call one of your variables `responseText`?
- Scoping might come in handy.
- You really might want to read up on XHR and how to do it. Right now, your code doesn't run on IE7/8.

A lot of the concerns will not apply to this as XHR only calls back once, but imagine this situation: you have this mysterious class `C` which has a callback called `feedback`, which accepts closures. This callback fires four times, and you need to pass *the same* variable to the four callbacks without possibility for the callbacks to change this variable. Your code breaks down on this one.
Trivial, I know, but it's worth going for the best in the first shot. You're gaining on following the DRY methodology as well.

How I would do this:

```
function callCObject(_c_init_vars, callback) {
  var tempObject = new C(); // Instantiating my "C" object, whatever it may be
  var tCallback = function() {
     callback.apply(this,_c_init_vars);
  }
  tempObject.callback = tCallback;
  tempObject.run();
}
```

Instead of manually instantiating C, I would do it as follows:

```
var myCallback = function(a,b,c) { console.log(a); console.log(b); };
callCObject([1,6], myCallback);
```

Just to prove the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/d3yAg/

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. Can you expand on "how to do XHR right" with regard to IE7/8? (I'm guessing you mean the IE "feature" where `this.responseText` isn't defined until `readyState==4`?)

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/xmlhttprequest_activex_ie has all the info! :-)

Comment: Sebastien, so your point was that I don't check for XMLHttpRequest support, and instead I just assume it is available? I'm fine with that, for the sake of a StackOverflow question (especially as XMLHttpRequest is available in IE7/8). If it was something other than that, and other than that `this.responseText` isn't defined until `readyState==4` in IE7/8, please come out and tell me exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: My point about CBC was only that your AJAX call will just plainly not run on IE7 or before. There was nothing more to it. On implementation, storing variables in the XHR object is all fine and good until you need to store a variable called `responseText` or any other reserved XHR keywords.